# How to recognize facebook cookie php- login with facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

Im using a facebook login with php only (no javascript), using FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.

When a user is login in the first time, I'm saving him in my database, and in the second time I'm just pop him out of the database.

The problem is that I don't know if this is the user's computer and add my own cookie so i can autolog him to my website next time.

Is there any way to check if this is the user computer or not.

In other words, is there any way to check if the user marked the checkbox "keep me logged in" whenever he logged to facebook?

Comment: you can add some of the user credentials in that autologin cookie, so you can use them to autolog https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/113781/

Comment: I know how to add a cookie... I'm asking how to check if I should when a user loging with facebook

Comment: Make a middle page. One page on your site where a button login with facebook exists with a checkbox, which leads to e.g. `yoursite.com/facebook_login.php`, and the last page is adding the cookie and performing the facebook login e.g. using the  FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.

Comment: I know I can do it but I'm asking if there's any way to avoid it and get this information from facebook.

Comment: I have experience only with Google+ and the way there is to use a refresh_token, because the normal token invalidates in very short time. You should examine Facebook API if they provide such service, so one you log in the user, you store the token in a cookie